# jquery select divs that are not in an iframe

Tags: jquery

I need select all div tags that are not in an iframe. what selector can I wrote for that? I need something similar to: `$("div:not(in iframe)")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `$("div")`.

Any element inside an `iframe` is going to be in a different document which you can't reach with `$()` anyway.